# Intra- and inter- observer error, and the intra-class correlation coefficient (ICC)

Tags: r, anova, reliability, psychometrics, intraclass-correlation

I have 3 observers, who each perform multiple observations in which they count a phenomenon. I'm trying to quantify both inter- and intra- observer error for this study. I'm new to this and am finding the analysis options quite confusing. Someone recommended using the ICC. I've mocked up some data below with "number of words" on a page as the count variable - this mimics my data structure. I read Shrout and Fleiss (1979), and since I want to generalize to a population of observers it looks like I want the Two-way random effects model, ICC(2,1).

My issues are:

1. for intra-observer error (or agreement), should I only include one observer per ICC? In other words, get the ICC for the repeated observations within observers?
2. for inter-observer error (or agreement), should I include all observers and the repeated observations, or should I aggregate the repeated observations so that there is only one for each observer?
3. I'm also not clear on whether I'd want the ICC for a single observation or averaged observations [i.e., ICC(2,1) vs ICC(2,k)].

Code:

```
# data with repeated observations
dat <- data.frame(
    pages = c("page1", "page2", "page3", "page4", "page5"), 
    Peter1 = c(236, 179, 203, 218, 195),
    Peter2 = c(232, 181, 198, 212, 197),
    Peter3 = c(225, 176, 205, 216, 191),
    Paul1 = c(227, 177, 204, 218, 196),
    Paul2 = c(236, 179, 209, 222, 199),
    Mary1 = c(234, 184, 201, 216, 191),
    Mary2 = c(238, 182, 200, 218, 193),
    Mary3 = c(240, 176, 206, 221, 197)
    )

library(psych)

# intra-observer reliability?
ICC(x = dat[, paste0("Peter", 1:3)])
ICC(x = dat[, paste0("Paul", 1:2)])
ICC(x = dat[, paste0("Mary", 1:3)])

# inter-observer reliability?
ICC(x = dat[, -1])
```

Comment: Interesting. My understanding is that Shrout and Fleiss described 6 ICCs which are selected on the basis of the experimental design.  You can't use a convenience sample of 3-raters and then analyze the data as if the observers were randomly selected from a population of all possible observers.  The psych package in R is quite descriptive about how this is done (https://personality-project.org/r/html/ICC.html). Prior to doing any analysis, you may want to determine appropriate sample sizes required to find a difference between observers. Five observations per rater might be a little thin.